# How to check if a number is present in a group of ranges?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

```
R1=[0,20]
R2=[15,20]
R3=[30,50]
Target=[0,50]
```

I need to check if the target range is covered by all the R(s).

In above example **0..20 and 30..50 is covered but not 20..30**

is there an easy way to check it?

Looping through all the numbers will decrease the performance because actually I need to deal with 10000s of ranges.

I can use either Python-django on server side or jquery on client side.

Comment: Are all ranges inclusive, meaning [1,10] means all numbers from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are in the range?

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. Are you saying that you need to test whether every number in the target range also appears in at least one of the Rn ranges? Are you looking to just get a true/false (is covered/isn't covered) result, or do you need a list of numbers from the target range that aren't covered?

Comment: @Nihathrael, yes. I need to alert the user "20..30 is not covered"

Comment: Wouldn't it be 21..29 that isn't covered? R1 and R2 both have 20, and R3 has 30...

Comment: my understanding is that you have to reduce your range to the smallest possible number of range capable of covering the same as the orginal ranges. in this case, [0, 20], [30, 50]. I think a simple o(n^2) algorithm can do that. I'll try to post an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sympy](http://sympy.org/):

```
from sympy import Interval

coverage = Interval(0,20) + Interval(15,20) + Interval(30,50)
target = Interval(0, 50)

return coverage.subset(target)
```

Or if you need actual result:

```
>>> target - coverage
(20, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your ranges are **stored** in order, you will have to visit each one, as one range may contain a min/max. So for N ranges the worst run time you could have would be O(N). So something like this:

```
Ranges = [[0,20],[15,20],[30,50]]
def inRange(targetMin,targetMax,Ranges):
    minV,maxV = Ranges[0][0], Ranges[0][1]
    for r in Ranges:
        if r[0] < minV:
                minV = r[0]
        if r[1] > maxV:
                maxV = r[1]
        if targetMin >= minV and targetMax <= maxV: #if we're in range, no need to check the others
                return True
    else:
        return False

print(inRange(0,50,Ranges))
```

Or non accumulating (where min/max is local to each range, not all the ranges)

```
def inRangeNonCum(targetMin,targetMax,Ranges):
    for r in Ranges:
        if targetMin >= r[0] and targetMax <= r[1]:
                return True
    else:
        return False

print(inRangeNonCum(0,20,Ranges))
print(inRangeNonCum(30,50,Ranges))
print(inRangeNonCum(20,30,Ranges))
```

Produces

```
>>> 
True
True
False
```

Your expected result. In either case the worst time is O(N). If your ranges were sorted in some manner, then you could look at the extreme ends, if the end's min is greater than the targetMax, then say look at the range 1/4 backwards from the end etc...

Comment: Your algorithm returns true, whereas the op states that for this example it should return false.

Comment: @Nihathrael You're right... I don't understand the question then

Answer (score 0):

```
ranges = [[0,20],[15,20],[30,50]]
target=[x for x in range(0,50+1)]
for x, y in ranges:
    range_object = range(x, y+1)
    target = list(filter(lambda x: x not in range_object, target))
    if not target:
        break

print("Not covered:" + str(target))
```

This should work and give you exactly what is not covered. It has to run over all numbers, but should be fairly efficient through the use of the filter function.

**EDIT**: works best when combined with the range merging proposed by @njzk2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [interval](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0) library:

```
import interval
r1 = interval.Interval(*R1)
r2 = interval.Interval(*R2)
r3 = interval.Interval(*R3)
t = interval.Interval(*Target)

In [11]: r = interval.IntervalSet([r1, r2, r3])

In [12]: r
Out[12]: IntervalSet([Interval(0, 20, lower_closed=True, upper_closed=True),
                      Interval(30, 50, lower_closed=True, upper_closed=True)])

In [13]: t_minus_r = interval.IntervalSet([t]) - r

In [14]: t_minus_r
Out[14]: IntervalSet([Interval(20, 30, lower_closed=False, upper_closed=False)])
```

You can simply test whether a value is in a given Interval/IntervalSet:

```
In [15]: 1 in r
Out[15]: True

In [16]: 1 in t_minus_r
Out[16]: False

In [17]: 20.00001 in t_minus_r
Out[17]: True
```

Comment: I tried to [revive this project](https://github.com/hayd/interval), and got it working in python 3... however having seen sympy probably already have this better I think I'll let it die.

Answer (score 0):

Using this algorithm

```
#Added a few ranges for demonstration puposes
ranges = [[25, 35], [0, 20], [5, 10], [15, 20], [30, 50]]

new_ranges = []

for range in sorted(ranges):
    for large_range in new_ranges:
        if range[0] >= large_range[0] and range[0] <= large_range[1]:
            if range[1] > large_range[1]:
                large_range[1] = range[1]
            break
    else:
        new_ranges.append(range)

print new_ranges

[[0, 20], [25, 50]]
```

`new_ranges` contain the consolidated ranges. Typically, if your range is covered, it will be contained in only one of the consolidated ranges. As they are sorted, searching through them is quite fast.

Comment: Nice idea, I used this to combine the ranges and used my snippet for the actual test. Using the merging was more than 5 times faster (for 30000 ranges) compared to using the unmerged ranges. It runs in 0.36 seconds(1.69 without merging) on my machine, which should be a useable result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a natural problem for Python [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) -- until proven empirically that you need something faster.

```
ranges = [ [0,20], [15,20], [30,50] ]
target = [0,50]
result = set(range(target[0], target[1]))

for a,b in ranges:
    result.difference_update(range(a, b))

print result  # set([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
```